# How to change the css styling on this div-container

Tags: html, css

I want to overwrite a given styling template:

Based on this example:
https://github.com/evilz/vscode-reveal/blob/master/views/logo.ejs

```
<div id="logo" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px; z-index: 1">
    <img src="Logo.svg">
</div>
```

I've added a custom css form based on this sample: https://github.com/evilz/vscode-reveal/blob/master/libs/reveal.js/3.8.0/css/theme/blood.css

```
#logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

The custom theme is loaded, but i does not change the setting on the logo.

Comment: `top` doesnt work unless there is a position of relative or absolute or fixed

Comment: Ok, i've changed it. But does not work either... It seems the css changes are not implemented at all.

Comment: interesting...have you used devtools to debug this? or cleared your cache?

Comment: Yes, i use devtools. I try to clear the cache again.

Comment: mabye you could try adding `!important` to the css rules?

Comment: This does the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline styles are interpreted as more important than the ones in the css file so to override them you need to use `!important`:

```
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px !important;
    width: 300px;
}
```

It would be better to remove the inline styles if you're allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because inline style on HTML takes priority over internal/embedded CSS.
So what you can do is to overight the HTML (considered as a bad practice)

```
<div id="logo" style="position: fixed; top: 100px; width: 300px; left: 20px; z-index: 1">
    <img src="Logo.svg">
</div>
```

or the best solution :

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="Logo.svg">
</div>
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```